# Div element width: 100% not actually 100% when another div is off the screen (position: absolute)

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make the background div actually 100% with other movable/floating divs that are positioned absolutely.

Width 100% is not accounting for the .floater div being far off the screen. (which the browser shows with scrollbars).

live example of problem: https://jsfiddle.net/h0arax9o/2/

Scroll to the right of the preview.
I would like the purple background to cover the entire document.

html:

```
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="floater"></div>
```

css:

```
.background {
   background: purple;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
}

.floater {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 1400px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Edit: for clarity, I would like the background to 'stretch' across the entire page, for example, if it was an image, when you scrolled in the example, the image would scroll as well.

I updated the example to showcase that.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.background {
   background: purple;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
}

.floater {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 1400px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="floater"></div>
```

Comment: This works by setting the background to be fixed, which makes sense, but I don't want the background to be "fixed". I want it to be 100%, for example, in the jsfiddle, the background isn't ~1500px, its 100% of the visible (~400px), and when you set it to fixed, its still ~400px but doesn't move.  Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: @naradlov - Please specify your problem clearer, maybe with an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
.background {
    background: purple;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.floater {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 1400px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/h0arax9o/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Please improve it by adding some comments as to what you changed and why your code answers the question.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a css reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

If you click on the gear icon on the top right of the css part of jsfiddle you can choose to normalize css. Here's a forked jsfiddle where I did that: https://jsfiddle.net/ckkoq3pn/

```
 _
```